# How to set Textview's attributes programmatic way?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

How can I set the value for the attributes for Textview in a programmatic way from XML code?

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text1" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text2" />
```

Comment: why would you do that? whats wrong with `LayoutInflater`?

Comment: You can create an object in Java class of TextView and use setText() method.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand this: `Programmatic way from XML code`

Comment: how can I set  attributes dynamically ,soI ask this question

Comment: How can I set the value for the attribute `layout_weight`,`layout_margin`  for textview in android dynamically from java code

Comment: did you see any answer below? thy all mention about `LayoutParams`

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);

    //set layout weight like this where 0.5 f is layout_weight
    LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f); 
        params.setMargins(10, 0, 5, 0);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setText("Text");
```

Comment: Sorry read THE UPDATED ANSWER. You need use setMargins() on params not textview.

Answer (score 0):

Basic information for your knowledge:
Each view that you take in XML layout is actually a class object that you are taking. Yes so those are classes like LinearLayout, TextView, Button, etc.

Now as said above those are classes so to access those programmatically, you can create an object of the particular view, access and apply available methods:

For example:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("Hello World!");
textView.setId(randomId);
textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Not include margin in this programme

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change width, height, gravity,... u have to use LayoutParams object of your textView

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams